# Visualforce page in step in approval process

Tags: visualforce, approval-process

Is it possible to create a Visualforce page for the page where an approver actually approves or rejects an approval request? To clarify; I've created an order object and orders have to be approved. So after the creation of an order the system starts an approval proces. The manager of the creator of the order gets an e-mail with a link to approve or reject the order. I want to create a custom VF page to which this link directs. The reason is that, if an order is rejected I want the manager to enter more information then just a comment.

Comment: Creating a visualforce will mean using apex for the approval process .Other way i could see is having some inline page for comments but users must be trained only to enter when they reject it or some backend logic.

Comment: It's no problem to use Apex for the approval process. I didn't think of it, it would be a good solution.

Comment: You want me to add as answer ?

Comment: Yes please. Do you also have an idea how to add a link to the VF page (including parameters) to an automated e-mail? I would probably need a VF e-mail template?

Comment: You can use href tag to generate in html template while if you dynamically want to build you may need visualforce template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a visualforce will mean using apex for the approval process .Other way i could see is having some inline page for comments but users must be trained only to enter when they reject it or some backend logic